# Request timeout while sending large files through rest service

Tags: java, android, rest

I have an error - timeouts while sending large files through rest service from mobile phone. My web application exposes REST api to different consumers like mobile phone. There are some other data sent with file like user personal data, details that he filled on some form etc.

I dont want to change server settings (timeout settings) but change the architecture of the solution.

I am not asking how to do that in mobile phone (there are different OSes) but how to expose proper REST API for mobile phone.

Do you met such scenario and have some example for a good solution? Is it possible and reasonalbe to send files in chunks fro mobile phone or something like that?

Security is already implementend - oath and some tokens in requests, so if it works already while sending other types of data it is not important in this question.

```
@POST
    @Path("/uploadDocument")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadDocument(
           @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {
```

Comment: I am new to the project and the code is too complicated to show it here. It its architecture is wrong, this is not just an exception to be repaired. People are sending 50MB files and I think it is not right for one POST or PUT REST method and for the server which handles big requests. I want to rewrite it and searching for some experience in developers who did similar things and would instruct me how to deal with such big files and when a file starts to become big... I am thinking of some chunking but dont know if it is possible and good solution. I think our business sold crappy API.

Comment: I added some code but for me it doesnt provide any value here. One POST for 50MB file...